# It's possible to have more than 2 condition in ag-grid text filter?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

In the default filters of ag-grid, it's possible to add one or two conditions (with AND or OR concatenation).

My question is if there is some way to have 3 or more concatenated conditions with the same logical operator (aside from create an entire custom filter).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, If you want to apply conditions b/w more than two parameters, you will need to implement your own `IFilterAngularComp`.

Read [this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-component)