# Ag-grid multiple tag filter on a column

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Ag-grid text filer currently supports maximum 2 tags to search on column.
i need to filter multiple tags(more than 2) on a column. How to achieve this ??.
Code looks like this.

```
condition2: {
        type: 'contains',
        filter: 'swimming',
    },
     condition1: {
        type: 'contains',
        filter: 'syn',
    },
    operator: 'AND',
  }
```

[image]

Comment: check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528932/its-possible-to-have-more-than-2-condition-in-ag-grid-text-filter

Comment: thanks,, this also helped to solve custom filter https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-text/#example-text-filter