# Ag grid add second OR or AND to the filter in column header

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have `ag-grid` and I set filter for columns:

```
"filter": 'agTextColumnFilter',
        "filterParams": {
          "filterOptions": ['equals', 'notEqual'],
```

and I can have only two values for filter:
[image: ag grid filter with AND]

`Starts with hhh AND Starts with`
But I want to have three or more properties, for example: `aaa AND bbb AND ccc AND ddd`
Allows Ag-grid for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply conditions b/w more than two parameters, you will need to implement your own IFilterAngularComp.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#filter-component

[It's possible to have more than 2 condition in ag-grid text filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59528932/its-possible-to-have-more-than-2-condition-in-ag-grid-text-filter)